# fgets and sscanf being skipped in c?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

In my code I'm making sure the user enteres one of the following abreviated classes however my fgets is causing me a lot of logic errors.

```
char class[3];
char arr3[5];
i = 0;
    while(i == 0){
        printf("Enter the class, either FR, SO, JR, SR, GR, RFR, or RSO\n");
        fgets(arr3, sizeof(arr3), stdin);

        if(sscanf(arr3, "%s", class) == 1){

            if(strcmp(class, "FR\0") == 1 || strcmp(class, "SO\0") == 1)
                i = 1;
            else if(strcmp(class, "JR\0") == 1 || strcmp(class, "SR\0") == 1)
                i = 1;
            else if(strcmp(class, "GR\0") == 1 || strcmp(class, "RFR\0") == 1)
                i = 1;
            else if(strcmp(class, "RSO\0") == 1)
                i = 1;
            else
                printf("Enter one of the classes.  Must be all caps.\n");
        }
        else if(sscanf(arr3, "%s", class) != 1)
            printf("An error has occured.\n");
    }
```

When I run the code, the first thing that happens is that it skips the fgets and then prints: 
Enter one of the classes.  Must be all caps.
Does this mean its reading something thats already in stdin?

Comment: `class[3]` is too-short-by-one to hold `"RFR"` or `"RSO"` as strings (no room for `'\0'`) so *Undefined Behavior* results when you pass an unterminated `class` to `strcmp`. Further the `"\0"` in , e.g. `"SO\0"` is superfluous. A *String Literal* already provides the *nul-termianting*. character. *Moral of the story* -- *Don't Skimp On Buffer Size!* Additionally, what, if anything, happens before your code snippet with `stdin` in important. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment, you have a lot of things wrong, but the biggest is *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!*. Your next major point of confusion is that `strcmp` returns ZERO when the strings match, not `1`. Don't try and remove the trailing `'\n'` included by `fgets` through truncation to a shorter array, simply use `strcspn` to remove it.

A *String Literal* provides the *nul-termianting* character, so the `"\0"` in `"SR\0"` is superfluous. Get rid of them.

But, *Congratulations*, your basic approach to taking user input (e.g. loop continually forcing the user to enter what is required) -- is the RIGHT approach.

Making those changes you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[BUFC];

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter the class, either FR, SO, JR, SR, GR, RFR, or RSO\n");
        if (!fgets (buf, BUFC, stdin)) {
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
            return 1;
        }
        buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;       /* trim newline from buf */

        /* strcmp equality return is 0 */
        if (strcmp (buf, "FR") == 0 || strcmp (buf, "SO") == 0  ||
            strcmp (buf, "JR") == 0 || strcmp (buf, "SR") == 0  ||
            strcmp (buf, "GR") == 0 || strcmp (buf, "RFR") == 0 ||
            strcmp (buf, "RSO") == 0)
            break;
        else
            printf("Enter one of the classes.  Must be all caps.\n");
    }
    printf ("\nclass: %s\n", buf);
}
```

(**note:** if you are compiling for a micro-controller, like Arduino or TI-MSP432, with limited memory, then you can reduce `BUFC` to `32` or so, but on x86 or x86_64, a 1K to 4K buffer generally ensures all normal lines of input encountered will be consumed -- even if the cat steps on the keyboard)

Above, checking the return of `fgets()` allows you to catch a manually generated `EOF` where the user cancels input by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux, or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/enterclasses
Enter the class, either FR, SO, JR, SR, GR, RFR, or RSO
banannas
Enter one of the classes.  Must be all caps.
Enter the class, either FR, SO, JR, SR, GR, RFR, or RSO
NO
Enter one of the classes.  Must be all caps.
Enter the class, either FR, SO, JR, SR, GR, RFR, or RSO
RFR

class: RFR
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.